# Optimizer and Estimator in Neural Networks

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, text-classification

When I started with Neural it seemed I understood Optimizers and Estimators well.

Estimators: `Classifier` to classify the value based on sample set and `Regressor` to predict the value based on sample set.

Optimizer: Using different optimizers (Adam, GradientDescentOptimizer) to minimise the loss function, which could be complex.

I understand every estimators come up with an Default optimizer internally to perform minimising the loss.

Now my question is how do they fit in together and optimize the machine training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: loss function link them together.

for example, if you are doing a classification, your **classifier** can take input and output a **prediction**. then you can calculate your **loss** by take **predicted class** and **ground truth class**. the task of your **optimizer** is to minimize the loss by modifying the parameter of your classifier.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I create 2 layer of  convolution, pooling, etc.., the `optimizer` take the final equation derived from such operations to minimize the loss. How is that I would be able to link such an optimizer with the classifier ?

Comment: basically, every layer have some variable that is trainable, the optimizer will calculate the gradient of loss regarding to all of them, then use the gradient to update the variable.  you can google how back-propagation works, there are many good tutorial to answer your question.